# Copy all files matching pattern from dir and subdirs into a single dir

Tags: linux, bash

If I wanted to copy all `*.so` files from `src` to `dst` I'd do:

```
cp src/*.so dst
```

However, I want to copy all `*.so` files from src and *it's subdirs* into `dst`. Any clues?

Comment: You will find your answer here. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24243

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try:

```
find src/ -type f | grep -i so$ | xargs -i cp {} dst
```

Comment: `find` can do pattern matching and execute commands. There's no need to pipe its output: `find src/ -type f -name '*.so' -exec cp '{}' dst/ ';'`

Comment: Yes, it can, however it's often easier to read a pipeline, also the pattern matching capabilities of `grep` far outweigh the simple shell patterns used in the `-name` parameter to `find`.  `xargs` is also far more powerful than the `-exec` parameter to `find`.

Comment: Solution of @jaquer is much better because on MacOSX xargs utility does not have -i option. But his solution works like a charm.

Comment: I was struggling with an error message on the -i argument to xargs until I read the comment from @bialix regarding jaquer's solution, which worked perfectly on my Mac. Thanks

Comment: Will this create subdirectories as needed?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `find src/ -type f -name '*.so'` ?

Comment: Also this does not preserve the subdirectories

Answer (score 24):

If you're using Bash, you can turn on the `globstar` [shell option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) to match files and directories recursively:

```
shopt -s globstar
cp src/**/*.so dst
```

If you need to find files whose names begin with `.`,
and/or files in and under directories whose names begin with `.`,
set the `dotglob` option also (e.g., with `shopt -s dotglob`). 
You can set them both in one command:

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob
```

Comment: Doesn't copy files in subdirectories starting with a . in their name

Answer (score 17):

I tried the command suggested by Mike:

```
find src/ -type f | grep -i so$ | xargs -i cp {} dst
```

but it ended up with dumping all the files into directory `dst` with their relative paths lost.

To keep the relative paths the command needs to be modified to this:

```
find src/ -type f | grep -i so$ | xargs -i cp {} dst/{}
```

Comment: +1. However, this assumes that the directories corresponding to the relative source paths exist under `dst`. In case that's not so, use `cp --parents`. Also, be sure to quote the filenames. Thus: `... | xargs -i cp --parents "{}" dst` (note that the last argument to `cp` is now "just" the destination directory). The command can be made even shorter (and probably faster) using the `-t` flag: `... | xargs cp --parents -t dst`.

Comment: @Stephan202 I had to use `... | xargs cp {} --parents -t dst.`

Comment: for those on a mac, `--parents` isn't available.  I used `ditto` in its place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246070/cp-parents-option-on-mac

Answer (score 10):

Another way of doing this is like this:

```
find src/ -type f -name "*.so" -exec cp {} dst/ \;
```

Comment: And this should reduce number of `cp` processes: `... -exec cp -t dst/ {} +`.

Comment: Hey Kamil! Thank you for the comment! Can you please explain me how your solution makes things faster! Always willing to learn more :)

Comment: When you end `-exec` with `;`, `{}` is replaced by one path at a time. You get a separate `cp` for every file. With `+` syntax `find` replaces `{}` with multiple results (up to a system-defined limit of command line length; restriction: `{}` must be the last thing before `+`, hence `cp -t`). Creating and terminating a process is relatively costly thing. For this reason it's good to use `+` whenever you expect lots of results. In this case copying lots of files might take a lot of time anyway so the difference may pass unnoticed; nevertheless it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The grep can be replaced by using find's **-name**:

```
find src/ -type f -name "*.so" | xargs -i cp {} dst/{}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me,

```
shopt -s globstar
cp src/**/*.so dst
```

does not copy `.so` files directly in src.
This does:

```
shopt -s globstar
cp src/**/*.so dst
cp src/*.so dst
```

or this

```
shopt -s globstar
cp src/{**/*,*}.so dst
```

But it solves the problem of copying things directly into dst, without preserving paths.

Answer (score 0):

For copying from an absolute path, I had to add a `sed` command.

Also, as `--parent` did not work properly (`cp: with --parents, the destination must be a directory`), I had to create the folders first.

```
find                    /root/src/ -type f        \
  | grep -i so$                                   \
  | sed             "s|^/root/src/||"             \
  | sed             "s|/\([^/]*\)so$||"           \
  | xargs -i mkdir  --parents          /root/dst/{}

find                    /root/src/ -type f       \
  | grep -i so$                                  \
  | sed             "s|^/root/src/||"            \
  | xargs -i cp         /root/src/{}  /root/dst/{}
```